# Testing a Vue component using element-ui component

Tags: vue.js, element-ui, vue-test-utils

I have a component that is using an [element-ui](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element) component.

**Tree.vue**

```
<div>
  <el-tree :data="treeData" :props="config"></el-tree>
</div>
```

I want to test the interactivity with the component (for example, to be able to click on one of the `el-tree` html elements), but when I'm using `vue-test-utils` `mount` to mount the `Tree` component, it doesn't render it's children component, like it `shallow`ing the component instead.

**Tree.test.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils';
import Tree from './Tree.vue';

const wrapper = mount(Tree);

it('renders element ui tree component', () => {
  console.log(wrapper.html());
});
```

**Outputs:**

```
<div><el-tree data="[object Object],[object Object]" props="[object Object]"></el-tree></div>
```

Any idea how can I fully render the `Tree` component, including it's children?

Comment: I think the problem here is how do You pass `treeData` property - I think it looks like it's somehow parsed wrong in the output.

Comment: It seems like your `Tree.vue` unable to recognize the `el-tree` component.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where element ui components were not recognized.

Had to import createLocalVue and ElementUI in the test file

```
import { shallow, mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import Editor from '../src/components/layout/Editor'
```

and then

```
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(ElementUI);
```

and then

```
describe('Editor', () => {
 let wrapper
 beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(Editor, {localVue}, {
    data : {
      x: '0',
      y: '0',
    }
  })
})

it('renders a vue instance', () => {
  expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're not importing the `el-tree` component properly. Vue is not translating the `<el-tree>` tag into a component, and is simply treating it as an html element instead.

Have a look at the element [quick start page](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart) for different ways to import the components and make sure you've got things set up correctly.

Add some more details if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

you should import element-ui in your test file.
check this out: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#applying-global-plugins-and-mixins.

however, I don't know how to import element-ui globally, so that I don't need to import it manually in every test file

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.